# ASP.net web application structure confusing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've explored the ASP.net web API framework and MVC 4. I understand the point of using web API that only return data then in client side we use javascript, ajax to handle all actions via HTTP verbs. On the other hand, MVC controller can return data and view we can handle event via [HttpPost] in controller.

I saw some people they make 2 projects in a solution: one is Web API in MVC 4 and the other is MVC 4 Internet Application. Is it a good idea? I didnt see the relation between two kind of projects. Can anyone explain me the how two project can communicate with each other, and what is the advantage and disadvantage of that way?

Note: in this solution he/she still uses Httppost to handle event and use MVC controller return view with Model binding.

Answer (score 1):

Well I guess this is going to be a pragmatic conversation...

For starters, it seems like the Asp.net WebApi and Asp.net MVC are going to be aligned in Asp.Net V-Next, so there is going to be One base controller class that will return what ever datatype you wish (ActionResult, Json etc).

And from the recent years experience I think the trend is to have a WebApi that exposes data and a portal(client) that is just a JS web application with no C# code that just calls the Api from the browser and does what it needs to do.

So that way we basically save one hup to the server(the MVC server) and we can directly call the API from the browser.

However some people would still argue about load balancing, scaling, caching etc that you could have if you keep the MVC tier there but still all those things could be done in the WebApi and JS application too...

So long story short, I think if you want to move with the trend I think you should go with a RESTful API and have your client to call it from the browser directly with JavaScript...

Comment: one more question: what is the common tools that you usually use to do the website with RESTful API and javascript

Comment: @TranDuyLinh I use Asp.Net WebApi to implement REST services because I've been working on Microsoft projects, so obviously they tent to use their own products, and KnockoutJS for our front end code...